# how can i store this created cookie key in a variable in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
request.session.set_test_cookie() <---- this will create a session with cookie id
```

but how can I store this cookie key in a variable in Django.

I've tried this, but it gives error.

```
id = request.session.set_test_cookie()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django provides an easy way to test whether the user’s browser accepts cookies. Just call the set_test_cookie() method of request.session in a view, and call test_cookie_worked() in a subsequent view – not in the same view call [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies).

so set_test_cookie() method is only for testing a is browser support cookie or not. if you want to check is browser support call session.test_cookie_worked() method

Create cookie in django as follow:

`def view(request):
  response = HttpResponse('response data')
  response.set_cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value')`

Retrieve cookie data:

`def view(request):
  if 'cookie_name' in request.COOKIES:
    value = request.COOKIES['cookie_name']`